# Getting Error while using WITHIN Clause in BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I Just try to get some custom Dimensions with a Code Snippet from the [BigQuery Cookbook](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4419694?hl=en):

```
​​​SELECT fullVisitorId, visitId, hits.hitNumber, hits.time,
MAX(IF(hits.customDimensions.index=1,
hits.customDimensions.value,
NULL)) WITHIN hits AS customDimension1,
FROM [tableID.ga_sessions_20150305]
LIMIT 100
```

When i try to execute it i get the following Error:

```
Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword WITHIN at [6:8]
```

I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: this query supposed to be run in BigQuery Legacy SQL! Add #legacySQL as the first row  and try again. see [Switching SQL dialects](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)

Comment: Oh perfect thank you. Do you know any workaround for StandardSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this query supposed to be run in BigQuery Legacy SQL!
Add #legacySQL as the first row as in below and try again. see also [Switching SQL dialects](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql) for more details

```
#legacySQL
SELECT fullVisitorId, visitId, hits.hitNumber, hits.time,
MAX(IF(hits.customDimensions.index=1,
hits.customDimensions.value,
NULL)) WITHIN hits AS customDimension1,
FROM [tableID.ga_sessions_20150305]
LIMIT 100
```